# Broken NTFS drive but no error in SMART, CHKDSK or F3?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs

I've got a Windows 10 installation which always crashes a few minutes after boot-up.

I already checked the drive using SMART, `chkdsk`, `Fight Flash Fraud` and `clamav`. No errors at all. I also checked the hardware thoroughly and cannot find any problems.

But there are some odd problems on the drive which I cannot figure out:

When I mount the drive from linux and try to read the content using `tar`, I get a lot of messages like these:

```
tar: Windows/System32/davhlpr.dll: Cannot stat: Input/output error
tar: Windows/System32/daxexec.dll: Cannot stat: Input/output error
tar: Windows/System32/dbgcore.dll: Cannot stat: Input/output error
```

This error leads to installing ntfs-3g-compressed, which does not exist any more and should be included into ntfs-3g... So the cause is something else.

Now I tried to copy the content from a different Windows 10 installation (in VirtualBox). Windows tells me "unexpected error 0x80070032" which is totally unrelated to copying files. according to microsoft:

> This error code is triggered when you try to set an external hard disk
>   as your backup location. The issue can also occur when you're trying
>   to install a major update to your Windows 10. The update relies on
>   files that can be accessed from a direct download from Microsoft or 
>   an automatic update through the Windows Update. The error code
>   0x80070032 arises when you are trying to activate the Automatic File
>   Backups setting. This option is located in the settings menu under the
>   backup option. When you restart your PC to accept the changes made,
>   the update fails to activate, thus the error code 0x80070032 appears.

How come `chkdsk` does not find any error even if run with `/r`?

I recently replaced the power cord to SATA drive, but this did not help. Might the bad power cable have caused the filesystem mess?

Comment: Seemingly random crashes and disk read/write errors could be a sign of memory failure or other hardware fault. I had a machine years ago that would, within about 30 minutes of booting, corrupt the registry and/or crash hard. Reinstalled several times with the same result until I did a memory check and found a bad stick. System was rock solid after that got replaced.

Comment: I did a memtest86. This found only high frequency hammering errors which are considered harmless by memtest86 and are out of warranty from memory manufacturers. I also did some burn in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to reinstall Windows. No Hardware issues at all.
The problem was a bad filesystem which wasn't bad according to chkdsk. 
Windows sucks. Windows 10 even more. 
I thought this should not happen with today's Journaling filesystems, and tons of recovery mechanisms.